# Poles and zeroes

Tags: number-theory

If $f$ be the function defined by 
$$f(x)=2sin\frac{x}{2}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-e^{ix}q^k)(1-e^{-ix}q^k)}{(1-q^k)^{2}}$$
where $q = e^{2\pi it}$

$h(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}; \quad \quad y(x)=-h''(x)\quad \quad g(x)=\frac{f(2x)}{f^4(x)}\quad \quad K(x)=\frac{y(x)}{g(x)}$

Prove that

$y(\pi)=y(\pi t)=y(\pi+\pi t)=0$

After simplification I get,
$$y(x)=-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\cos x/2}{\sin^3x/2}+2\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k^2q^k}{1-q^k}\sin k x$$
but got stuck how to prove the upper cases by using this

And how can I show that K is double periodic with period $2 \pi$ and $2 \pi \tau$ and K has no singularities